# Variable-size object in shared_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, smart-pointers

Suppose I want a variable-size array with a bit of a header up front stored in a `std::shared_ptr`. I could do something like

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
struct obj {
  char headerCode;
  unique_ptr<short[]> data;
};
shared_ptr<obj> make(unsigned len) {
  return shared_ptr<obj>{new obj{'x', unique_ptr<short[]>{new short[len]}}};
}
```

But this would lead to three allocations: one for the `shared_ptr` control block, one for the `obj` and one for its `data`. With `make_shared` it is possible that the first two share some memory:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
struct obj {
  char headerCode;
  unique_ptr<short[]> data;
  obj(char headerCode, short data[]) : headerCode(headerCode), data(data) {}
};
shared_ptr<obj> make(unsigned len) {
  return make_shared<obj>('x', new short[len]);
}
```

With low-level allocation I can make the object and its data share some memory:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct obj {
  char headerCode;
  short data[0];
};
shared_ptr<obj> make(unsigned len) {
  obj* o = reinterpret_cast<obj*>(malloc(sizeof(obj) + len*sizeof(short)));
  o->headerCode = 'x';
  return shared_ptr<obj>(o, free);
}
```

Are these two techniques allowed by the standard? If not, is there something similar which is allowed? Is there something which makes this work in a standards-conforming way with only a single memory allocation? Preferrably without having to store an allocator or deleter object in every instance?

Comment: Why use `reinterpret_cast` to convert `void*` to `obj*`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: without explicit cast my `g++` says `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘obj*’ [-fpermissive]`. But you are right, a `static_cast` is probably more appropriate here.

Comment: Yes, of course it won't convert implicitly, but `reinterpret_cast` is a sledgehammer, it is not necessary here. `static_cast` is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these two techniques allowed by the standard?

The first one is fine, the second uses a zero-length array as a member (`data[0]`) which is not valid C++, but is supported as an extension by some compilers.

> Is there something which makes this work in a standards-conforming way with only a single memory allocation?

Currently it's pretty difficult without http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3641.html which would allow something like this:

```
struct obj {
  char headerCode;
  short* data;
};

shared_ptr<obj> make(unsigned len) {
  auto p = make_shared<char[]>(sizeof(obj) + sizeof(short)*len));
  short* s = static_cast<short*>(p.get() + sizeof(obj));
  return shared_ptr<obj>(p, ::new(p.get()) obj{'x', s});
}
```

This allocates an array of `char` with enough space for an `obj` and the array of `short`, then uses placement new to construct an `obj` into that memory, and creates another `shared_ptr` which shares ownership with the one that owns the `char` array. When the last `shared_ptr` that owns the memory drops its reference the `char` array will be correctly deleted, but the `obj` object's destructor will not be run, so it's important that you don't rely on its destructor having any side effects (ideally it will have a trivial destructor).

You might be able to do it today using `allocate_shared` with a custom allocator which allocates additional space for the array of `short`, but since you don't know how the implementation will arrange the control block and your object in the space allocated it's quite difficult to work out where the `short` array begins, and the allocator needs to be stored in the control block.

Comment: Even if it is very unlikely to cause problems with `short`, don't forget to account for alignment. In general, it's not guaranteed that `p.get() + sizeof(obj)` is suitably aligned for whatever you want to place after it, although pretty much all platforms will make pointers have equally strict or stricter alignment requirements compared to `short`.

Comment: Yes, I did consider it, but in this case it should be safe, because the trailing pointer member should be aligned so that a `short` can follow it immediately. In general you might need to add (up to) `alignof(T)` bytes to the allocation and use `std::align` to place an array of `T` correctly.